# Get lower nibble of a byte and replace Hex value

Tags: c#, binary

I need to replace the hex value 0xA with a 0 and get only the lower nibble of a hex value.

[image]

This is what  I have at the moment:

```
    private void ParseContactID(int ContactID_100, int ContactID_10, int ContactID_1)
    {
        // (A=0)

        string Hunderds = ContactID_100.ToString("X").Replace((char)0xA, '0');
        string Dozens = ContactID_10.ToString("X").Replace((char)0xA, '0');
        string Singles = ContactID_1.ToString("X").Replace((char)0xA, '0');


        int HunderdsLower = StringToHex(Hunderds) & 0x0F;
        int DozensLower = StringToHex(Dozens) & 0x0F;
        int SinglesLower = StringToHex(Singles) & 0x0F;
    }
```

Should I & with 0x0F to get the lower nibble or 0xF0?
And is there a way to replace 0xA without converting it to a string first?

Comment: Do you want to replace any 0xA (if found) in byte 12,13 and 14 with 0? And then extract the lower nibble of these three bytes? Is this what you want? And can 0xA exist in either higher or lower nibble?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that the code you currently have does what you think it does - `(char)0xA` is a line feed, not the letter 'A', so it won't be replacing anything (since the `ToString("X")` won't produce a line feed. As you've suspect however the string conversion can be done away with completely.

To get the lower nibble, you need to AND with `0x0F`. As far as the conversion of `0xA` to `0`, there are a couple of options, but if you can be sure that the lower nibble will only contain values `0x0 - 0xA` (0 - 10), then you can use the modulo operator (`%`) which if we modulo 10, will convert `0xA` to 0, whilst leaving values 0 - 9 unchanged:

```
var hundreds = (ContactID_100 & 0x0F) % 10;
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any reason for you to use string conversion at all.  This could simply be:

```
int hundreds = (ContactID_100 & 0x0F) % 10;
int dozens = (ContactID_10 & 0x0F) % 10; // I wonder why "dozens" instead of "tens"... ?
int singles = (ContactID_1 & 0x0F) % 10;

int contactId = hundreds * 100 + dozens * 10 + singles; // assuming "dozens" is "tens"...
```

To get the lower nibble, you just have to mask away the top nibble with `& 0x0F`.
To make A = 0, modular division can work.  Make sure to put `()` around the `&` statement, since [the `%` has higher precedence than the `&`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

If you prefer to not use the `%` operator, an `if` check may be faster:

```
int hundreds = ContactID_100 & 0x0F;
int dozens = ContactID_10 & 0x0F;
int singles = ContactID_1 & 0x0F;
if (hundreds == 10) { hundreds = 0; } // since 0xA is 10
if (dozens == 10) { dozens = 0; }
if (singles == 10) { singles = 0; }
```